# Why can $x\notin (A\cap B)$ be written as $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was looking through the solution for a question asking to show that the symmetric difference $D$ of two sets can be expressed as: $D=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ using $\;x\in A\;$ , $\;x\in B \:$ and $\:x\notin (A\cap B)$. They rewrite this as $\;x\in A\;$ or $\;x\in B\:$ and $\;x\notin A\;$ or $\;x\notin B\;$. Normally these make sense to me since I just look at the different cases possible, for example $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$ has two cases $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\in A\cap C$ but in this question I just can't see how you can go from $x\notin (A\cap B)$ to $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$

Comment: What have you tried to do? Have you tried to do a wenn-diagram? There's only fore regions $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$, $A\cup B$ and the rest of the universe. Just check the sameness of $x\notin (A\cup B)$ and $x\notin A\lor x\notin B$. Or you could use  the definition of $A\cup B$ and set up a truth table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall what it means for $x$ to be a member of $A \cap B$. We have 
$$ x \in A \cap B \iff x \in A \text{ and } x \in B $$
Hence, if $x \not \in A \cap B$, $(x \in A \text{ and } x \in B)$ is wrong. As a conjunction is right iff both individual statements are right, it is wrong iff at least one is wrong. That is $(x \in A \text{ and } x \in B)$ is wrong means that $x \in A$ is wrong **or** $x \in B$ is wrong, that is we have $x \notin A \text{ or } x \notin B$.

This follows also directly from de Morgan's laws 
$$ \neg (p \land q) \equiv \neg p \lor \neg q $$
or the statement for sets 
$$ \complement (A \cap B) = \complement A \cup \complement B $$

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap B$ is the intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$. $x\in (A\cap B)$ means that $x$ is in $A$ and in $B$ at the same time. Similarly, $x\notin (A\cap B)$ means that $x$ does not belong to $A$ and $B$ at the same time. So either $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$.